# How to insert empty string into a date column using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo

I am using a PDO prepared statement to insert values. One of the values is a date, and sometimes it can be empty. In MySQL schema, the date column is set to allow NULL values.

Let's assume date_column is a date and it allows NULL. When I do this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl(date_column) VALUES(?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(['']);
```

This is giving me this error:

**SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '' for column 'date_column' at row 1**

In phpMyAdmin, I can execute this query without errors. It sets the date to **0000-00-00**

```
INSERT INTO tbl(date_column) VALUES('')
```

Isn't that the same query that is executed by PDO behind the scenes in the code example above? What's wrong?

All I want is to be able to insert empty string '' as a date without errors. I don't care if it is set to **0000-00-00**

Comment: If the string is empty - don''t insert it.

Comment: @u_mulder the query above is just an example. the actual query that I'm having problems with inserts many values.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

This is a fundamental problem:

> All I want is to be able to insert empty string '' as a date.

Strings are strings, and dates are dates.  You should not want to insert an *empty string* into the column because that makes no sense.  Instead, you should want to insert either a `NULL` value or the default value.

So, your code should look like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl(date_column)
    VALUES(NULL)
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO tbl(date_column)
    VALUES(DEFAULT)
```

The fact that MySQL does better type checking on prepared queries with parameters is actually a good thing.

Comment: But why does MySQL allow me to insert empty string '' to a date column, and the date becomes 0000-00-00. I want to do that via PDO prepared statement, and insert '' and MySQL should just treat it normally without throwing an error.

Comment: @marmita . . . The issue is where the `''` gets converted to a date.  For a string hardcoded in the query, this might happen during the compile phase.  For a string passed in as a parameter, the compiling phase has passed, and the execution engine sees the string where it expects a date.  As I say, the fundamental problem is that you want to assign an empty *string* to a *`date`* column.

Comment: I think the issue is with PDO. Because the execute() method treats all parameters as strings. And it doesn't complain if the date is a string as long as it is in the right format. It only complains when the string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Empty string is not a null... NULL is a NULL

```
$stmt->execute([null]);
```